# npm install --save-dev @ts2.0 Invalid tag name "@ts2.0"

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

So when i type :

```
npm install  @ts2.0 --save-dev
```

I have this error :

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@ts2.0": Tags
>   may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

Any ideas why ?

Regards and thanks

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17980

Comment: Which package are you trying to install? Do you have any links to the package page / repo?

Comment: the @ts2.0 type

Comment: If you wanted to install TypeScript v2.0 it should be  `npm install --save-dev typescript@2.0`

Comment: You should remove this npm GitHub issue. This is unrelated to npm. You're trying to install a package that doesn't exist. Try what Saravana mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when copy/pasting from a pdf. Typing it by hand got it work for me

Comment: Yes, you are right, when we copy it text is like  `—save-dev` but it should be  `--save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

@Saravana's answer worked for me. My code is:

```
npm install --save-dev  jest
```